# Is a component bound to just one element?

Tags: javascript, twitter-flight

I'm trying to wrap my head around Twitter flight. Lets say I have a Program page, it has 16 elements dealing with managing a program, CRUD operations, AJAX requests etc... Using twitter flight, do i need to create a component for each and every node element or for  the Program page and attach each element to a function in the Program component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A component is instantiated for each element you attach it to. If you have a list of DOM nodes, you can call `.attachTo` on each one and instantiate a set of components for all the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to attach a component to every node. You could have a single component attached to the document which does everything, but it makes sense to break that down in to smaller pieces of functionality. IMO, a component should represent a feature.

For example, you may have a component which communicates with an API via ajax, another which handles submissions for a particular form, another which manages the content of a list. Just how much a single component does is up to you. For the sake of portability, reusability and ease of maintenance it makes sense to keep components small and well-defined.

Saying that, you probably don't want to make lots and lots of tiny components. I wouldn't want to create one for every item in a list, but I might create one for every list on a page.

A single instance of a component can be attached to a DOM node. Components have access to the full DOM tree extending from their root node.